# sonarqube intergration with Jdeveloper

Tags: java, sonarqube, jdeveloper

I have been trying to intergrate my Java code with the jdeveloper sonarqube extension.I followed the guide at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140808212955-5016041-run-sonar-analysis-from-jdeveloper but when I right click on the project and try to analyze from jdeveloper, I get the error **bash: sonar-runner: command not found**
However, when I run the analysis from terminal using sonar-runner it runs successfully. What am I missing? Please advice on what I am missing so as to run the analysis directly from jdeveloper. Thanks

Comment: I would add sonar-runner to your PATH, add sonar-runner to a directory already a part of your PATH, or create a shortcut from inside a directory in your PATH to where it lives. (Another guess is terminal uses Windows Cmd Prompt while right clicking uses Bash emulator)

Comment: I have already added sonar-runner to my PATH, that is why I am able to run the analysis from terminal. However the same fails in jdeveloper.